# Gnome setup to show icons for windows along bottom of screen?

Tags: gnome, icons, redhat-enterprise-linux, window-manager

I am using Gnome window manager on RedHat Enterprise Linux v2.6.9-67 and recently my Gnome sessions started behaving differently and I do not know what I did to cause this or to restore the old behavior.

Previously, I had icons for each window along the bottom of the screen in a bar, now there is still a bar, but no icons for windows appear.  Consequently, once a window is minimized, I cannot find anyway to raise it again.  Starting a new Gnome session from scratch has same behavior.

Please suggest what I can do such that I can create a Gnome session where I can re-raise windows after minimizing them by having their icon appear again along the bar at bottom of window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps will add icons for each window along the bottom of the screen in a bar:

1. Right-click on the panel.
2. Choose Add to Panel.
3. Scroll down the list of items in the Add to Top Panel dialog, then select Workspace Switcher.
4. Click Add.